# How to disable a button if textfields are empty in xcode 8 , swift 3

Tags: swift3

I just made my first app, when I run app and click button if textfields are empty ,it stops and I get an error 
How do I disable button if textfields are empty so my app doesn't crash ?
I saw previous posts but nothing worked for me , it's for xcode8 swift 3
Will really appreciate any help , thank you 
Btw it works fine if I fill all the textfields and then click buttons .
Zainee

Comment: what's the error? add the error text to question

Comment: can you share the tried code Please ?

Comment: It crashes , on console I get message but it did not make much sense to me , it says something about textfield being nil .

Answer (score 1):

First bind delegate of textfield to view controller.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let value = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if value.characters.count > 0 {
        self.btnSubmit.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        self.btnSubmit.isEnabled = false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you , would this work for all textfields and buttons ? Or I have to do this for individual textfields ?

Comment: This for only one. For multiple, you need to declare variable var currentTextField = UITextField() and assign current textfield to this variable in textFieldDidBeginEditing. Create function (as per your requirements) for checking all textfield value and call from shouldChangeCharactersIn range.

Comment: I am very new to Xcode , this is too complicated for me, I have alot of questions , do you suggest any book or video that I can watch to better understand it, will really appreciate it, thank you JD for your time and help.

Comment: Ray Wenderlich : https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/swift. Appcoda and obviously Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you JD ,you are the best :))                                                                        I may ask you more questions after I check that website , hope I can communicate with you again. Thank you again for your time and guidance .